# Where should ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit be set in an Azure Function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The latest release of the Azure Functions tooling (version 1.0.9) generates the following warning at startup:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is set to the default value of 2. 
This can limit the connection throughput to services like Azure Storage. For 
more information, see https://aka.ms/webjobs-connections.
```

The information in the provided link suggests setting this value in the Main method of an Azure WebJob. However, Functions don't have a Main method. Where is the best place to set this value in an Azure Function App (particularly when using a Consumption plan)?

Comment: What plan do you have for your function app? Consumption or App Service ?

Comment: Oh didn't realize that would matter. This for a Consumption plan.

Answer (score 2):

For consumption plan it's 50 and you can't change it.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/v1.x/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptConstants.cs#L84

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link. What I don't understand is that if you can't change it, why was the mentioned warning added to the local Azure Functions cli tooling?